Did anyone ever try making a 3D mouse for the PC?
I'm actually wondering about things that were tried a long time ago and couldn't be done, and then now they could be simple cheap peripherals.
Like, in the 486 days when I worked at a disreputable computer store, we sold a VR headset that looked like you're sitting in the middle of a dark room looking out a distant window. Now you can just slide your smartphone into a special holder that straps on your head.

3D mice (6DOF mice like the SpaceOrb 360) and motion capture peripherals are two very different things, could you pick one and make your question about that? “Things that were tried a long time ago and couldn’t be done” is far too broad.

About half of them were ill-advised attempts to build better controllers for 3d games before 2-stick controllers and mouselook properly entrenched.

@StephenKitt - Oh man! I had a SpaceOrb and  played Descent on it, thought it was wonderful and a little before its time.  Thanks for the nostalgia hit

There have been many 3D mice and other kinds of six-degree-of-freedom input device. None of them have had lasting and large-scale success. The problems include:

They're much more expensive than ordinary mass-produced mice.
Integrating them with software tends to require custom modifications to the software.
As far as I know, none of the current widely used GUIs have support for 3D input, and if they did, few applications would support it, because of the lack of readily available hardware. It's a classic chicken-and-egg problem.

I found a website about them, spacemice.org, which has links to four current suppliers:

3D Connexion, who are currently being moderately successful in CAD.
Space Control.
Spatial Freedom.
Lexip

Many years ago I worked for Robocom, producers of the BitStik, a three-axis joystick for the Apple II and BBC Micro. They produced some decent CAD software, by 8-bit computer standards, which used it. However, when they started development for IBM PC and compatibles, they reckoned the MkI Microsoft Mouse would be a lot more acceptable to customers, and abandoned the BitStik.
Further devices from comments:

Flock of Birds used magnetic sensors, and worked well as long as there wasn't any ferrous metal nearby.


http://www.mindflux.com.au/products/ascension/flockofbirds.pdf Worked great, just so long as there was no ferrous metal anything nearby!

Beyond chicken-and-egg, I would argue that it's much more a solution in search of a problem. As you say, if people need such a deivce they are out there, but few people actually have a problem where such a device would help. (Unlike, say, joystick-with-rotation and other asix sensors).

3D Connexion has some sort of relationship with Logitech. I've got one on my desk, and it really does help with CAD manipulation.

I have a couple 3D Connexion devices- good for MCAD and PCB design. Spacepilot and the more compact Spacemouse. They're useful, but once you get used to using the keyboard optimally (and if the app developers have done their job well) they're not that essential.

3D Connexion is the industry standard for 3D CAD programs around here (no affiliation, but I've been using several of their products over the years). If you talk around here about a 3D mouse, that's what they'll think you mean. They work well for every professional grade mechanical 3D CAD program (such as SolidWorks, Inventor, Fusion360) and a lot of the less mechanical ones and are considered essential for some of the work. Not because you can't work without them, but because of the speed increase you get once you're used to them.

@Mast: Thanks, added.
